# count the rows based on array object

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the rows based on like and unlike value in an array.I want to count the rows based on like and unlike value.I need to display like:3 and unlike:1.Now it display like:0,unlike:0 '$content' value is either `{"userid":"1","like":"1"}` or `{"userid":"1","unlike":"1"}`

[image]

```
$like_count     = 0;
$unlike_count   = 0;
while($like_fet = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $content    = $like_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'];
    $datas  = json_decode($content);
    foreach($datas as $item)
    {
        $like    = $item['like'];
        $unlike = $item['unlike'];
        if($like != '' && $unlike == '')
        {
            echo "like";
            $like_count++;  
        }
        if($unlike != '' && $like == '')
        {
            echo "unlike";
            $unlike_count++;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason/design why you store that inforamtion as json in your mysql database?

Comment: ya I have some reason to do like this

Comment: better you would have used boolean value for like and unlike .

Comment: "ya I have some reason to do like this" - No offense but ... I'm presumptuous enough to assume "some" means "not a very good" ;-) But anyway.... No, seriously; there might be a good reason - it just doesn't often show here on stackoverflow/[php] :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$like_count=0;
$unlike_count=0;
while($like_fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json = json_decode($like_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'], true);
    if ( isset($json['like']) ) {
        $like_count += $json['like'];
    }
    if ( isset($json['unlike']) ) {
        $unlike_count += $json['unlike'];
    }
}
```

depending on how CONTENT_VALUE actually works this can probably simplified to

```
$like_count=0;
$unlike_count=0;
while($like_fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json = json_decode($like_fet['CONTENT_VALUE'], true);
    if ( isset($json['like']) ) {
        $like_count++;
    }
    else if ( isset($json['unlike']) ) {
        $unlike_count++;
    }
    else {
        trigger_error('CONTENT_VALUE without like/unlike element', E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I caught error as '<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'

Comment: yeah, sorry - I forgot the `, true` on json_decode to get an array instead of an object.